# Changing column names from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with all the companies listed in the S&P500 with their daily data. However in each dataframe column name there is an undesired `"/n"` appended to it and I want to remove it.

I get the following error:

```sh
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('*.\n.*', '')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 1843, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 2716, in replace
    self._parent, pat, repl, n=n, case=case, flags=flags, regex=regex
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 619, in str_replace
    compiled = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\re.py", line 234, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line 651, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0 (line 1, column 1)
```

This is the function causing the error:

```py
def remove_extra_characters(df):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('*.\n.*', '')
```

Comment: `x.strip()` will remove all of the new-line characters at the beginning and end of a string and is easier to read than `replace('\n', '')`

Comment: `replace()` doesn't use regular expressions. You cannot write "patterns" such as `*.\n.*` The dot and asterisk will be ***literally*** treated as dot and star. It will not be interpreted as "match zero or more of any character." If you want regular expressions, use `re.sub()`

Comment: Can you post more of the actual code please, or an example of the dataframe, so we can test our solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! New-lines be gone! :)

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name\n\n\n', 'Age\n\n'])

df.rename(columns={old:old.strip() for old in df.columns}, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: You could also write, `df.columns = filter(lambda x: x.strip(), df.columns)`

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. But unfortunately another one arose. I'll need to open another question for that though...